How to count number of business days between two dates in AnyLogic?
How we count number of days between two dates excluding holidays in AnyLogic?
I tried the following function but it counts all days including non-business days.
differenceInCalendarUnits()

I appreciate it if someone could help me with that.

Well, this is such a complex task (which holidays, which country, what counts as a holiday? Here in Germany, regions have special days...) that there is no build-in support from AnyLogic nor Java, afaik.
You need to find a specific Java package that supports this, surely there is something out there.
Or you define the holidays yourself via a schedule and compute it manually
